How does Antlr4 support both integers and decimals in terms of lexicon?
I wrote a case study that can perform conventional mathematical operations on integers and decimals
grammar Calculation;

calculation: expr EOF;

// Parser rules
expr: expr (ADD|SUB) expr
    | expr (MUL|DIV) expr
    | expr POWER expr
    | expr MODULAR expr
    | LEFT_BRACKET expr RIGHT_BRACKET
    | SQRT LEFT_BRACKET expr RIGHT_BRACKET
    | NUMBER
    ;

// Lexer rules
ADD: '+';
SUB: '-';
MUL: '*';
DIV: '/';
LEFT_BRACKET: '(';
RIGHT_BRACKET: ')';
INT : [0-9]+;
NUMBER: INT ('.' [0-9]+)?;
POWER: '^';
SQRT: 'sqrt';
MODULAR: '%';

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

However, the above syntax will throw a warning when parsing (1+1), with the warning content being: line 1:1 mismatched input'1 'expecting {'(), NUMBER,'sqrt'}。
when I added |INT after |NUMBER, everything was normal. Why?

You have overlapping token lexer rules.  (INT and NUMBER).  When you have that, the first rule that matches "wins".  There is no backtracking.  Adding the | INT production made your grammar work for that example, but then 1.0+1.0 won't parse.  (Try it.) I think you need to reorder the lexer rules' i.e. put NUMBER before INT, and (I think) don't define NUMBER in terms of INT.

Alternatively, get rid of INT entirely if your grammar doesn't need to distinguish the two kinds of number (integer and decimal).  (That kind of thing is often handled in a later phase; i.e. when analyzing the parse tree emitted by your generated parser.)
